# Concatenation kills me

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

Can anyone help me put this together in the right way? I'm a noob at this. I'm using a while loop to put some info into a column one time. Just to populate the existing users. I think I have everything else right, with the exception of being brain dead when I try to glue strings together in a mysql statement!

```
mysql_query( "UPDATE `tuser` SET `AthleteID`='  " .  strtoupper( substr($row["LName"], 0, 2)) . $row["SkillshowUserID"]  .  " 'WHERE `SkillshowUserID` = `SkillshowUserID`;'");
```

Comment: Make sure you use `mysql_real_escape_string` to prevent your webapp from having a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks! I don't think that'll be an issue, this is a one time use piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

Take your PHP logic out of your query. You're only making your life more difficult:

```
$athleteId = strtoupper(substr($row["LName"], 0, 2)) . $row["SkillshowUserID"];
mysql_query( "UPDATE `tuser` SET `AthleteID`='$athleteId' WHERE `SkillshowUserID` = `SkillshowUserID`;");
```

A cleaner query made it easy to see you had an extra quote in there and needed some spacing between your `AthleteID` value and your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: +1. I'd actually go a step further and add another variable, `$sql = "UPDATE ...` and concatenate the SQL text into a string, and then follow that with a call to `mysql_query($sql)`, and add the check for the return from the call to mysql_query... at the point I'm calling mysql_query, I'm less concerned with the actual SQL text being submitted, and more concerned with handling the return. Trying to do that all in one line just looks confusing.

Comment: Perhaps I have more problems with my code than I thought :(  I've done these suggestions and no go. I'm not too worried about injection, this particular file is for a one time use.

Comment: <?php

require_once('resources/connection.php');



echo 'hello noob' . '<br />';

$query = mysql_query('SELECT LName, SkillshowUserID FROM tuser WHERE SkillshowUserID = SkillshowUserID');
$athleteId = strtoupper(substr($row["LName"], 0, 2)) . $row["SkillshowUserID"];
$update = "UPDATE `tuser` SET `AthleteID`='$athleteId' WHERE `SkillshowUserID` = `SkillshowUserID`;";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
 mysql_query( $update);
}

Comment: Perhaps I'm just going about this the wrong way altogether. The original advice I got was to use a foreach loop. I can seem to pull the two fields, and glue them together and spit them out to a page. But I cannot seem to get them into the database--Script Kiddie Phase be damned!